# Inputting other calculation into DATEDIFF

Tags: php, mysql, date

My client is requesting the database to be able to calculate days from `date1` to `date2` and I have used `DATEDIFF`, but is it possible that I can add extra calculation into the coding?

For example:

```
(date1-date2)/365*0.1
```

Can this calculation be done?

This is the code I have using on my `output.php`

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT *,DATEDIFF(mdate,pdate)/365*0.1
FROM contacts WHERE DATEDIFF(mdate,pdate)");



    echo 
    "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Difference Date</th>
    <th>Purchased Date</th>
    <th>Maturity Date</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Passport/ID</th>
    <th>Contact No.</th>
    <th>Mailing Address</th>
    <th>Beneficiary Name</th>
    <th>Swift Code</th>
    <th>Bank Account</th>
    <th>Bank Name</th>
    <th>Bank Address</th>
    <th>Bank Contact No.</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['DATEDIFF(mdate,pdate)'] . "</td>";
      //echo "<td>" . $row['ddate'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['pdate'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['mdate'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['amt'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['first'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['last'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['pid'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['cno'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['madd'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['bene'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['swc'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['bacc'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['bank'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['badd'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['bno'] . "</td>"; 
      echo "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>";

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

Comment: you mean `DATEDIFF(mdate,pdate)/365*0.1`?

Comment: Yes, `DATEDIFF(mdate,pdate)/365*0.1` is what I want to do, but it doesn't seem to output the result.

Comment: Right now I am using this,
`"SELECT *,DATEDIFF(mdate,pdate) FROM contacts WHERE DATEDIFF(mdate,pdate)");`

and it's showing the date difference correctly.  

Once I change the code to:

`DATEDIFF(mdate,pdate)/365*0.1` 

the database output gives me blank output.

Comment: check for mysql error? your query should work

Comment: Well, the table is showing properly.  It's the DATEDIFF not showing any values within the table.

Comment: looks like you posted the old code, can you show the code with `datediff(..)/365*0.1`?

Comment: I apologize for posting the old code, I have updated the code on my first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo at:

```
echo "<td>" . $row['DATEDIFF(mdate,pdate)'] . "</td>";
```

It should be

```
echo "<td>" . $row['DATEDIFF(mdate,pdate)/365*0.1'] . "</td>";
```

To avoid this, you can alias the calculated field in your query like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT *,DATEDIFF(mdate,pdate)/365*0.1 as difference 
                             FROM contacts WHERE DATEDIFF(mdate,pdate)");
```

And reference it like this:

```
echo "<td>" . $row['difference'] . "</td>";
```

Comment: Ah, thank you very much. It's working now.
Was wondering is it possible to go on with the `difference` result in the ouput and add furthur calculation into it?  eg `difference+(one of the column)`?

Comment: @Alex, I'm afraid not, you need to rewrite the `difference` calculation, (unless you wrap the whole thing in a subquery).